# Como usar INSERT INTO (Valor Currency) + SELECT (Valor String) SQL DB Acess

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Estou tentando inserir alguns dados em uma coluna formato `Currency`, mas os dados são `String`. Tentei fazer a conversão usando o  `Convert(Dados_String, Currency)`, mas também não deu certo.

Segue o comando:

```
INSERT INTO Tabela1(Dados_Currency)
SELECT Convert(Dados_String, Currency)FROM C:\Users\Servidor\Desktop\DBs\DB2.Tabela2)
```

Erro:

> Err: -2147217900
>   Função 'convert' indefinida na expressão.
>   Query: INSERT INTO Tabela1(Dados_Currency)
>   SELECT Convert(Dados_String, Currency) From (C:\Users\Servidor\Desktop\DBs\DB2.Tabela2)

Comment: Não seria `SELECT Convert(Currency, Dados_String)`?

Comment: Sempre usei do outro jeito, mas por via das duvidas fiz o teste do modo que citou, e deu o mesmo erro.